# How can I prevent anyone on the web from seeing comments on my Google+ profile picture?

Tags: privacy, google-plus

When I view my profile as "anyone on the web", they see one post on my profile. This post if of me selecting my profile picture, and includes my friends' comments on that picture.

I don't mind my profile picture being public (how else will people find me?), but I don't want my friends' comments to be visible to the public. How can I change this?

Comment: Don't think you can. You can obviously disable any further comments, or delete the ones that are there, but if someone comments on a public post their comment is public.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/165492/how-to-change-privacy-when-i-change-profile-picture-on-facebook
Can we answer this? I posted since July but no one answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @AI Everett is 100% correct. The only suggestion I would make in addition to his is this:

- Copy your existing profile picture (if you really like it and want to keep it, else upload a new profile picture; it is your choice). Leave this image in the album called "Scrapbook photos".
- Move your existing profile picture, which will include your friends' comments (I'm guessing you want to keep them), from Scrapbook photos to a different album. You can use an existing, private album, or create a new album that is accessible only to certain people or circles.
- Use the new version of the picture in your Scrapbook photos as your profile picture. Make sure to disable comments on in it!